# How to join linked server tables with openquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I want to join tables from two different linked servers. I am  not sure how to do that.

First query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PANTS,'
SELECT
LONG
,SHORT
FROM JEANS
```

Second query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SHIRTS,'
SELECT 
WHITE
,BLACK 
 FROM STORES
```

Let's say long is in the `stores` table and I want to join on it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

According to the query you supplied, you could do it like this:

```
Select Pants.Long, Pants.Short,
    Shirts.White, Shirts.Black
  From OpenQuery(PANTS, 'Select Long, Short From Jeans') As Pants
  Join OpenQuery(SHIRTS, 'Select White, Black, Long From Stores') As Shirts 
    On Pants.Long = Shirts.Long;
```